# GROUP BY and 2 LIMITS

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

Imagine this table

```
Name | Date | Value
--------------------
Olli | 2019 | 2
Olli | 2018 | 2
Olli | 2017 | 2
Olli | 2016 | 1
Olli | 2015 | 1
Olli | 2014 | 1
Pete | 2019 | 3
Pete | 2018 | 3
Pete | 2017 | 3
Pete | 2016 | 2
Pete | 2015 | 9
```

I want to select the quotient of a short-term mean (the latest 3 rows) and the all-time mean per name:

```
Olli: 2 / 1.5 = 1.3333
Pete: 3 / 4 = 0.75
```

Without the grouping by name, I can select all components  easily:

```
SELECT MEAN(value) FROM tbl WHERE name = 'Olli' -- all time mean, used directly in final query 

-- for the short term mean I use a CTE:
WITH short_term_tbl AS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = 'Olli' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3)
    SELECT MEAN(short_term_tbl.value) / MEAN(table.value)
    FROM short_term_tbl, tbl
```

But how can I generalize this to all names?

I'd be very happy to find a solution that works on both mysql and postgresql.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 8.0 (which you seem to be using since you are using a CTE, that is only available starting with this version of MySQL), this can be done as follows using `row_number()`:

```
select name, avg(case when rn <= 3 then value end) / avg(value)
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by date desc) rn from mytable t
) t
group by name
```

The subqueries assign a rank to each record whithin groups sharing the same `name`, orderede by descending `date`. Then the outer query does conditional aggregation.

Comment: Oh perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Now my use case is a bit more complicated in practice. Instead of computing `avg(value)`, I need expressions like `value*value`, i.e. the sum of squares. how does this work with the `case when rn <=3...` expression?

Comment: @OlliD-Metz: just: `avg(case when rn <= 3 then value * value end) / avg(value * value)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get your custom average:

```sql
SELECT Name, 
  AVG(CASE WHEN RowNum <=3 THEN Value END) / AVG(Value) AS avg_custom
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Date, Value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC -- Rank rows by date, within "name" groups
    ) AS RowNum
  FROM tbl
) src
GROUP BY Name
;
```

It should work in Postgres as well.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sSjYhFUALV5vZgi7pEpjQW/1)